# How to use VLOOKUP to return Multiple Values from Single Variable

Tags: google-sheets

##### `Package Payments` Sheet

|  | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Users** | **Total Numbers** |
| **2** | User 1 | 2 |
| **3** | User 2 | 4 |
| **4** | User 3 | 1 |
| **5** | User 3 | 2 |
| **6** | User 3 | 4 |
| **7** | User 3 | 7 |

##### Desired Results

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Users** | **Total Numbers** |
| **2** | User 1 | 2 |
| **3** | User 2 | 4 |
| **4** | User 3 | 1,2,4,7 |

Here's my current formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Client Payments"; JOIN(",", VLOOKUP(B2, 'Package Payments'!B2:E, 2, FALSE))})
```

I'm using `VLOOKUP` to search for a variable, and return values related to that variable in a single cell.

I'm trying to create another formula for my project.

I had thought this code would reiterate  and produce the results for all users.  I also want to avoid using query as I want to repeat the code throughout the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

`=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(D1=$A$1:$A$6,$B$1:$B$6,"")))` :

[image: answer for this question]

Even though this formula contains an ArrayFormula function it still needs to be copied down to E2, E3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=textjoin( ", ", true, filter('Package Payments'!C$2:C, 'Package Payments'!B$2:B = B2) )`

Alternatively, try this pattern to get a multi-column table that shows all numbers for all usernames:

```
=filter( 
  query( 
    { 
      'Package Payments'!B2:C, 
      countifs('Package Payments'!B2:B, 'Package Payments'!B2:B, row('Package Payments'!B2:B), "<=" & row('Package Payments'!B2:B)) 
    }, 
    "select Col1, max(Col2) 
     where Col1 is not null 
     group by Col1 
     pivot Col3", 
    0 
  ), 
  sequence(counta(unique('Package Payments'!B2:B)) + 1) > 1 
)
```

To place those results in your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18MB08W-ED81iJACN3yyk6cybL8wInPp25211D2eAZj8/edit#gid=2145725139), looking results up by client name, put this formula in cell `'Package Clients'!J1`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    "Package Payments"; 
    transpose( 
      query( 
        transpose( 
          iferror( 
            vlookup( 
              B2:B, 
              filter( 
                query( 
                  { 
                    'Package Payments'!B2:C, 
                    countifs('Package Payments'!B2:B, 'Package Payments'!B2:B, row('Package Payments'!B2:B), "<=" & row('Package Payments'!B2:B)) 
                  }, 
                  "select Col1, max(Col2) 
                   where Col1 is not null 
                   group by Col1 
                   pivot Col3", 
                  0 
               ), 
                sequence(counta(unique('Package Payments'!B2:B)) + 1) > 1 
              ), 
              sequence(1, 99, 2), 
              false 
            )  
          ) 
        ), 
        "", 
        9^9  
      ) 
    ) 
  } 
)
```

Comment: Hi there! I tried the first code you sent:
—
=textjoin( ", ", true, filter('Package Payments'!C$2:C, 'Package Payments'!B$2:B = B2) )
—

It works, but it's only fetching values from a single user. I tried extending the search for the variable by using :
 'Package Payments'!B$2:B = B2:B
However, it is not working, it is only displaying one value. I want it to display values related to the proeperty. I appreciate you giving the alternative formula. However, I wanted to collate the results to a single row.

Comment: The second formula gets all the results for a username in the same row. If that is not what you wanted, consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: Hi Bud! Thanks, here's a link for the Google Sheet File: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18MB08W-ED81iJACN3yyk6cybL8wInPp25211D2eAZj8/edit?usp=sharing 

If you'll check on the Package Payment Tab. There are two columns there labelled. Package Payments, and Client Payments. I want Package Payments to have the same Result as Client Payments.

Comment: Edited the answer. Your sample spreadsheet has more than 30,000 blank rows on most tabs. Delete those superfluous blank rows _before_ applying the array formula.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposed solution:
[image]

Formula Used (Improved - to include open range as well):

```
=ArrayFormula({UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A,A1:A<>"")),transpose(regexreplace(trim(query(transpose(REGEXEXTRACT(query(A1:A&"~"&B1:B,,3^6),REGEXREPLACE(query(A1:A&"~"&B1:B,,3^6),"("&UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A,A1:A<>""))&"~)(\d+)","$1($2)"))),,4^6))," ",","))})
```

Answer (score 0):

### Formula

```
=BYROW(TOCOL(UNIQUE(A2:A), 1), LAMBDA(r,
   {r, JOIN(",", FILTER(B2:B, A2:A=r))}))
```

[image: Sample Calculation]

### Explanation

1. [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653?hl=en) and [TOCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en) are combined to create unique list of users without a blank value.
2. [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) passes each row one-by-one into a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) function
3. [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) stores the current row's value in the variable `r`
4. [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en)'s formula creates a 2-column array:

   - The first column is the value stored in `r`
   - The second column's is returned by filtering the **Numbers** column B2:B for all rows where the **Users** column A2:A = `r`, then [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) is used to concatenate the results.

### Functions

[BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) [TOCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en) [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653?hl=en)